# How to refresh MSA token via the OnlineIdAuthenticator [UWP app]

Tags: rest, authentication, uwp, onedrive

I've asked this question on the UWP forum but have been directed here to see if anyone can help.

I use the OnlineIdAuthenticator from a C++ UWP app to access a users OneDrive files.  This works well.  However after an hour the token expires so I need to refresh it.  I tried two approaches:

1) I took a look at the OneNote sample here: https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal

Looking at AttemptAccessTokenRequest() within OneNoteServiceSamplesWinUniversal.Shared/OneNoteApi/LiveIdAuth.cs:

```
var createMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, MsaTokenRefreshUrl)
{
    Content = new StringContent(
    String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TokenRefreshRequestBody,
        ClientId,
        TokenRefreshRedirectUri,
       _refreshToken),
       Encoding.UTF8,
       TokenRefreshContentType)
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(createMessage);
    await ParseRefreshTokenResponse(response);
}
```

However I get a 400 response: error=invalid_request
error_description=The provided request must include a 'refresh_token' input parameter.

I can't see any way to obtain the refresh token via the OnlineIdAuthenticator.

2) I call OnlineIdAuthenticator::AuthenticateUserAsync() again but this time only with a "wl.signin" scope, as mentioned in LiveAuthClient.cs from the LiveSDK:

https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK

This works and I get a new token! Unfortunately when I try to refresh it again (at the 2hr mark) it returns the same token and I then get a 401 unauthorized when I try to use it.

So has anyone successfully refreshed the access token via OnlineIdAuthenticator ?  If so I'd appreciate knowing how you've done it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

OnlineIdAuthenticator does not support refresh token as far as I know.
did you try making direct POST request to https://consent.live.com/AccessToken.aspx? 
Check here for more details - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750952.aspx

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).